# Perform an OR operation on same field from multiple rows SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am a beginner trying to achieve a simple operation in SSRS using Visual Studio 2019. I have a query which returns a table as follows

```
ID | Name | Married
1  | Jack | Y
2  | Jack | N
```

The number of records might vary depending on the number of results. On the report, I want to display only the field 'Married' once. The value of the field will be determined using an OR operation, i.e. if the field 'Married' is 'Y' for any one record, I want to display a 'Y' on the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Values are either `Y` or `N`, you should be able to use something like

```
=MAX(Fields!Married.Value)
```

If you report is grouped by, for example, `Name` then this will give you the MAX value within each group which is probably what you want.

If this does not help, edit your question and show

- Your report design
- Row Group panel plus details of grouping
- A larger sample of data
- Expected results from that sample data

Comment: Hi Alan. That was exactly what I was looking for. You are a life saver! Thanks!